# Programming language and framework used for the GUI of Network Manager in Llinux

Tags: linux, user-interface

What is the programming language for making native gui applications in linux like network manager, where we give IP address and all. My requirement is to make a GUI application where no additional packages are required.I have checked many options like Gtk, wxpython etc. But every environment requires additional packages to be installed. Suppose I am using the same GUI environment for Network Manager or so, I don't need to install any additional packages.Can anybody please tell the GUI environment for Network Manager?

Comment: Are you talking about `nmtui` screen?

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful .....I am talking about the following gui , http://pad3.whstatic.com/images/thumb/7/74/Set-up-a-Network-in-Ubuntu-Step-3.jpg/670px-Set-up-a-Network-in-Ubuntu-Step-3.jpg